# Python, using UDP ports to transfer data from common pool makes threads crawl to a halt

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp

I'm quite stuck with while implementing a proxy tunnel. Based on pysoxy, I basically split it in half, a local "half" that deals with connecting to the client, and a remote "half" that does the proxying to the destination. The two parts communicate with each other via UDP.

The problem is, I keep on getting 100% CPU usage even when loading a simple page, performance is abysmal, and clearly the threads are getting super stuck.

I'm mostly sure this is about my usage of UDP sockets, but I tried making sure there is no blocking io or similar stuff hindering performance. And yet, I'm seeing the threads crawling even going from one line to the next.

I've tried to make an MCVE but it escapes me. The part I'm worried about the most is this:

```
    def proxy_loop_inbound(destination_socket, connection_details, stop_event, connection_queue):
        while not EXIT.get_status() or not stop_event.is_set():
            with connection_queue["lock"]:
                for index, proxy_loop in enumerate(connection_queue["queues"]):
                    if int(proxy_loop["id"]) == connection_details["id"]:
                        proxy_loop_content = base64.b64decode(proxy_loop["proxy_loop"])
                        if int(proxy_loop["sequence"])==inbound_sequence:
                            del connection_queue["queues"][index]
                            while True:
                                _, ready_to_write, _ = select.select([], [destination_socket], [], 0.01)
                                if ready_to_write:
                                    break  # Break the loop if the socket is ready to write
                                time.sleep(0.01)  # Sleep for a short duration to yield to other threads
                            destination_socket.send(proxy_loop_content)
                            break
                        else:
                            pass

def proxy_loop_outbound(destination_socket, connection_details, stop_event):
    while not EXIT.get_status() or not stop_event.is_set():
        try:
            ready_to_read, _, _ = select.select([destination_socket], [], [], 1)
            if destination_socket in ready_to_read:
                data = destination_socket.recv(BUFSIZE)
                if not data:
                    return
                while True:
                    _, ready_to_write, _ = select.select([], [udp_socket], [], 0.01)
                    if ready_to_write:
                        break  # Break the loop if the socket is ready to write
                    time.sleep(0.01)  # Sleep for a short duration to yield to other threads
                udp_socket.sendto(proxy_loop_outbound_details.encode(), ("127.0.0.1", UDP_PORT_WRITE))
        except BlockingIOError:
            print("Blocking IO error")
            pass
            # No data available
        except socket.error as err:
            stop_event.set()
            error("Loop failed", err)
            return
```

Both loops are the same mirrored on the other side of the proxy. These proxy loops are spawned for each connection, so for every request there are two such threads, and there is a UDP listener thread that will append the (possibly unordered) data to a list that is shared between threads. The threads will keep on doing the back and forth of the data until the socket is closed by either the client or the destination.

Sometimes threading is so blocked I get a second and a half to go from non blocking line to the next (i.e. literally time between two prints). Sometimes I get full seconds to do the write to the UDP port.

Also, this wrecks havoc on my ability to properly close the threads, as keyboard interrupts are basically never caught.
What am I doing wrong?

I'm putting the whole code here to try the whole thing out:

local part: https://dpaste.org/E4FVT

remote part: https://dpaste.org/68EtV

Comment: If you're already exchanging data between threads via UDP, why don't you use multiprocessing? Multithreading in python has the risk of blocking the GIL when performing certain operations. By using multiprocessing, you'd throw that problem away, and wouldn't need to call `time.sleep(0.01)` anymore inside your code, giving you even more performance.

Comment: @CarlHR so I did just that and while the problems regarding the impossibility of closing the threads went away (a great improvement, thanks!), now *every* cpu is at 100% and performance is still abysmal. I can’t seem to find a good way to use udp ports that will not end up with this situation.